# FMOD - Unable to play simultaneous sounds

Tags: c++, fmod

I am wondering if I am doing something wrong. I have set up my SoundManager class to have 5 different channels, in my game some sounds may be played at the same time, like the gun being fired and the enemy "hurt" sound... This is how I set up FMOD and the function I call to play the sounds in a manner that they are always rewound to the start:

```
void SoundMgr::init(){

    System_Create(&fmodsys);
    fmodsys->init(5, FMOD_INIT_NORMAL, 0)
} 

void SoundMgr::play(string name, int chan){
    if(chan == 1){
        fmodsys->playSound(FMOD_CHANNEL_FREE, soundMap.find(name)->second, true, &chn1);
        chn1->setMode(FMOD_LOOP_OFF);
        chn1->setPosition(0, FMOD_TIMEUNIT_PCM);
        chn1->setPaused(false);
    } else if(chan == 2){
        fmodsys->playSound(FMOD_CHANNEL_FREE, soundMap.find(name)->second, true, &chn2);
        chn2->setMode(FMOD_LOOP_OFF);
        chn2->setPosition(0, FMOD_TIMEUNIT_PCM);
        chn2->setPaused(false);
    } else if(chan == 3){
        fmodsys->playSound(FMOD_CHANNEL_FREE, soundMap.find(name)->second, true, &chn3);
        chn3->setMode(FMOD_LOOP_OFF);
        chn3->setPosition(0, FMOD_TIMEUNIT_PCM);
        chn3->setPaused(false);
    } else if(chan == 4){
        fmodsys->playSound(FMOD_CHANNEL_FREE, soundMap.find(name)->second, true, &chn4);
        chn4->setMode(FMOD_LOOP_OFF);
        chn4->setPosition(0, FMOD_TIMEUNIT_PCM);
        chn4->setPaused(false);
    } else if(chan == 5){
        fmodsys->playSound(FMOD_CHANNEL_FREE, soundMap.find(name)->second, true, &chn5);
        chn5->setMode(FMOD_LOOP_OFF);
        chn5->setPosition(0, FMOD_TIMEUNIT_PCM);
        chn5->setPaused(false);
    }

}
```

And in the game I have (this is just an instance but it happens with most sounds):

```
....
sMgr->play("gunshot", 1);
....

sMgr->play("rat_hurt", 3);

...
```

However the result is very random, with the two sounds playing rarely at the same time whereas most time only one of the two plays...

Also I have a looping mode:

```
void SoundMgr::playRepeat(string name, int chan){
   if(chan == 1){
      fmodsys->playSound(FMOD_CHANNEL_FREE, soundMap.find(name)->second, true, &chn1);
      chn1->setMode(FMOD_LOOP_NORMAL);
      chn1->setPosition(0, FMOD_TIMEUNIT_PCM);
      chn1->setPaused(false);
   } else if(chan == 2)

....
```

But that too is randomly interrupted by other non looping sounds, even if played on different channels?

I'd really appreciate any help that you may be able to provide

Thank you in advance for any help you may be able to provide.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know your problem but I can recommend using an array to store the `chn1`..`chrN` values, so that you avoid all this `if`s in your code by just doing:

```
  assert(chan >= 0 && chan < sizeof(channel_array));
  channel& the_chn = channel_array[chan];
  fmodsys->playSound(FMOD_CHANNEL_FREE, soundMap.find(name)->second, true, &the_chn);
  the_chn->setMode(FMOD_LOOP_NORMAL);
  the_chn->setPosition(0, FMOD_TIMEUNIT_PCM);
  the_chn->setPaused(false);
```

Comment: thank you, that's a solution i'd gladly consider once i figure out why the channels are not working properly though..

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue. This setup actually works fine when I initialize FMOD with 1024 channels instead of 7

```
fmodsys->init(1024, FMOD_INIT_NORMAL, 0);
```

Channels are apparently very light weight and need not to be cleaned after use hence they recommend on their forum to always initialize 1024 on PC.